# Why is it called landscaping?

Tags: landscaping

I am a landscape gardening student and have been asked why the word landscaping is used and its origin. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 3):

Landscape - The visible features of an area.

Landscaping - changing the visible features of an area to be more pleasing.

Answer (score 3):

Wikipedia covers the [origin of the word landscape](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landscape).

Land is fairly obvious and the Wikipedia entry goes on at length about the origin of "scape". Here's a snippet.

On the suffix -scape:

> 'Landscape' is distinguished from 'land' by the suffix -scape, which
>   is equivalent to the more common English suffix -ship.[3] The roots of
>   –ship are etymologically akin to Old English sceppan or scyppan,
>   meaning to shape (Merriam-Webster dict.2000. This suffix designates
>   "something showing, exhibiting or embodying a quality or state"; as
>   such, it generates an abstraction upon the term landscape. The suffix
>   -ship thus designates the abstract ‘‘nature’’, ‘‘state’’ or ‘‘constitution’’ of something; these words are interlinked both as
>   abstract essences (e.g. the nature or constitution of something) and
>   as concretized and institutionalized entities (e.g. nature, the state,
>   a constitution). The suffix -shaft and the English -ship are cognate,
>   meaning essentially "creation, creature, constitution, condition).

Answer (score 1):

The word landscape has been explained in the other two answers, but have a look at the work of Capability Brown - he changed landscapes on a major scale, creating hills, dales, lakes and suchlike, transforming the original landscape into something altogether different. He did, though, work mainly under the direction of a Landscape Architect - so that makes Capability the 'landscaper' because he carried out the works. That's landscaping on a major scale, but creating a rockery and planting, or terracing with hard materials changes the landscape to a degree. Landscape gardening is somewhat different from simply being a horticultural student, or a garden designer, although all may include landscaping aspects, in particular, designing. The official dictionary definition of landscape gardening is "the art and practice of laying out grounds in a way which is ornamental or which imitates natural scenery".

Comment: Capability Brown did some pretty amazing and long lasting stuff. Definitely one of the heavies in the field.

Comment: Better get to know Frederick Law Olmstead...He is the father of Landscape Architecture. An amazing human that all Americans should know. http://www.nps.gov/frla/historyculture/index.htm

Comment: In what way does this answer the question?

Comment: @jmusser: to whom is your query directed?

Comment: @Bamboo Your answer doesn't say why it's called landscaping.

Comment: @jmusser Doesn't it? Well, yours is a point of view, I guess - just goes to prove you can take a horse to water, but you can't make it drink... if you can't see that it adds anything, well, that's your privilege. I don't feel the need to explain or defend my contribution.

Comment: @Bamboo :) My what is a point of view?

Comment: @jmusser In this case, an opinion, or both literally and psychologically, what you see from where you are!